# jquery recursive function to non-recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, recursion, progress-bar

i am sorry this question might be one of those "stupid questions". I have this round progressbar that works perfectly, when i click the button named "animateButton". But I want to start the progressbar with a function call, but the function does not have a name, because its recursive in the progressbar, i guess. How do I make the function to start the progress when i call a function like this startIt()?.

```
      $(function() {
      var $topLoader = $("#topLoader").percentageLoader({width: 60, height: 60, controllable : true, progress : 0.0, onProgressUpdate : function(val) {
          $topLoader.setValue(Math.round(val * 100.0));
        }});

      var topLoaderRunning = false;
      $("#animateButton").click(function() {
        if (topLoaderRunning) {
          return;
        }
        topLoaderRunning = true;
        $topLoader.setProgress(0);
        $topLoader.setValue('0kb');
        var kb = 0;
        var totalKb = 500; //100=2.7 1000=27

        var animateFunc = function() {
          kb += 1;
          $topLoader.setProgress(kb / totalKb);
          $topLoader.setValue(kb.toString() + 'kb');

          if (kb < totalKb) {
            setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
          } else {
            topLoaderRunning = false;
          }
        }

        setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);

      });
    });
```

I got it working as easy as this:

```
     startLoader = function() {
    var $topLoader = $("#topLoader").percentageLoader({width: 60, height: 60,    controllable : true, progress : 0.0, onProgressUpdate : function(val) {
  $topLoader.setValue(Math.round(val * 100.0));
      }});

   var topLoaderRunning = false;
if (topLoaderRunning) {
  return;
}
topLoaderRunning = true;
$topLoader.setProgress(0);
$topLoader.setValue('0kb');
var kb = 0;
var totalKb = 500; //100=2.7 1000=27

var animateFunc = function() {
  kb += 1;
  $topLoader.setProgress(kb / totalKb);
  $topLoader.setValue(kb.toString() + 'kb');

  if (kb < totalKb) {
    setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
  } else {
    topLoaderRunning = false;
  }
}

setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);

   };
```

Comment: Could your provide an example of wishful thinking? How would your code look like with your requirements?

Comment: it would be function1(){...... startloader();} --- startloader(){working loader code}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have all the pieces, you just need to reorder them a bit. Give your function a name, then assign that name to the click event. Then you can explicitly call the function by name at the end.

Untested code below, but I've used this principle many times.

```
$(function() {
  var $topLoader = $("#topLoader").percentageLoader({width: 60, height: 60, controllable : true, progress : 0.0, onProgressUpdate : function(val) {
      $topLoader.setValue(Math.round(val * 100.0));
    }});

  var topLoaderRunning = false;

  var startIt = function() {
    if (topLoaderRunning) {
      return;
    }
    topLoaderRunning = true;
    $topLoader.setProgress(0);
    $topLoader.setValue('0kb');
    var kb = 0;
    var totalKb = 500; //100=2.7 1000=27

    var animateFunc = function() {
      kb += 1;
      $topLoader.setProgress(kb / totalKb);
      $topLoader.setValue(kb.toString() + 'kb');

      if (kb < totalKb) {
        setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);
      } else {
        topLoaderRunning = false;
      }
    }

    setTimeout(animateFunc, 25);

  };

  $("#animateButton").click(startIt);

  startIt();
});
```

Comment: hey, thx I tried this before, but the function is not called, maybe because it is outside of this function? Because I need to call it outside the loader and I dont want the animateButton, but I want it to  be executed after something in another function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
$(function() {
  var $topLoader = $("#topLoader").percentageLoader({width: 60, height: 60, controllable : true, progress : 0.0, onProgressUpdate : function(val) {
      $topLoader.setValue(Math.round(val * 100.0));
    }});

  var topLoaderRunning = false;
  var startIt = function() {
    // function body...
  };
  $("#animateButton").click(startIt);
});
```

You can always assign functions to variables if you need to access them by name.

Comment: A function declaration can also be used instead of an assignment and function expression.

Comment: hey, thx I tried this before, but the function is not called, maybe because it is outside of this function? Because I need to call it outside the loader and I dont want the animateButton, but I want it to  be executed after something in another function.